# Parse Netstat Data - Real Time

Tags: swift, bash, macos, shell, networking

I want to parse the data from this command in OS X version of netstat:

```
netstat -i -w 1
```

This provides me an update each 1 second for the bytes in and out, and each second a new line appears with that second's update.  The output provides individual lines with packets, errors and bytes for both input and output - A new line each second.  Sample Output:

```
                input        (Total)           output
   packets  errs      bytes    packets  errs      bytes calls
      198     0     203028        192     0     111266     0
```

Basically, I need to be able to take the data from each of the seconds, so for the first second,  I would want four variables:

```
A) Input Packets = 198
B) Input bytes = 203028
C) Output Packets = 192
D) Output bytes = 111266
```

This needs to happen, as each line is added, until such time as I stop the netstat from running.

Ultimately, the data is used in another application using Swift/XCode, which will use that live data to graph data throughput in real time.

I have looked at doing this natively with Swift 3/Cocoa for a MAC app, but simply could not find any good information.

So - any ideas how this might be achieved?

Comment: Small update, which might be useful for some people - I still haven't solved the problem completely, but here is some additional information.  Firstly, I needed a way to limit the command "netstat -i -w 1" from running forever... I needed to kill the command at small intervals, the command I found which sorts this on mac easily is:  "netstat -i -w 1 & sleep 5; kill $!"  - this kills the read every five seconds (minus the quotes).